# What is this thing called?

Tags: android, dialog

What is thing called when you first open an app and a transparent dialog comes up filling the screen and it shows you how to navigate the app. Usaully only shows once after you install then never again until you clear cache or delete the app and reinstall.

Sorry I'm new :)

Comment: A [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)? Or maybe a [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: I think it's most commonly accomplished with a FrameLayout (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html).

Comment: It seems to me that you are describing the [ShowCaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an "Instruction Overlay".